# How to vertically align text and equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, boxes, alignment, box

How could I vertically move the third line on the left upward so that it doesn't appear broken with the two lines above?

[image]

I'd like to obtain this.

[image]

I have used this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\quad\hbox{}\hfill
$\left[\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3+4}}\right]$ \finalhyphendemerits=0 \parfillskip=0pt \par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE! If the paragraph is followed by another paragraph, how do you want it to look? (My suggestion is to avoid that tall formulas in inline text. In the example you show, you could for example slash the fraction.)

Comment: I really need to write things like that, so I can't avoid it. I changed pictures to show how next paragraph should look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your setting of `\finalhyphendemerits` and `\parfillskip` are wrong, because they propagate to the following paragraphs. You need to enclose them in a group.

Clearly, a macro is advisable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \unskip\nobreak
  \hfill\penalty50\quad\hbox{}\hfill
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}{$\left[#1\right]$}%
  {\finalhyphendemerits=0 \parfillskip=0pt \par}%
  \prevdepth=\fontchardp\font`y
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
\solution{\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{3+4}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex

\end{document}
```

I first raise down the object by its height, then raise it by the height of a capital letter. Finally, I set the `\prevdepth` to the depth of a letter with a descender so as to cover our tracks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, prof!

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `\raisebox`, and a simplification of your code;

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\quad\hbox{}\hfill
    \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}{$\left[\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3+4}}\right]$}%

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}` to precisely place the baseline one line down.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: you're right – I just used trial and error to write the code faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but here is a macro `\fright` that puts the expression into a `minipage` that has the width of the given expression. The minipage is top-aligned and shifted up by the height of a `(` character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\chrht}
\settoheight{\chrht}{(}
\newlength{\wdth}

\newcommand{\fright}[1]{\settowidth{\wdth}{#1}\begin{minipage}[t]{\wdth}\vspace{-\chrht}#1\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex \hfill
\fright{$\left[\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3+4}}\right]$}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `raisebox` that math expression as the negative difference between normal height and its height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\noht}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\f@size pt}{#1}}
\makeatother

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\quad\hbox{}\hfill
\noht{$\left[\dfrac{\frac12}{3+4}\right]$} \finalhyphendemerits=0 \parfillskip=0pt

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\quad\hbox{}\hfill

\end{document}
```

[image]